# Exceeding Maximum Update. Running in to infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have some forms in tabs this is one but when ever i click to view this particular form i get this error : Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops. i have narrowed the error down to this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        if(mode === 'create') append();
      }, [append])
```

and this

```
 

     const watchKeyOfficers = useWatch({ name: 'keyOfficers' });
    
      // Disable selected option on next select
      useEffect(() => {
        if(watchKeyOfficers) {
          setUsers(prevUsers => {
            const newWatchKeyOfficers = watchKeyOfficers.map(ko => ko.staffName?.userid);
            const newUsers = prevUsers?.map(u => ({ ...u, isDisabled: newWatchKeyOfficers.includes(u.userid) }))
            return newUsers;
          })
        }
      }, [watchKeyOfficers])
    
      const watchBranchId = useWatch({ name: 'branchId' });
    
    
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const branchId = watchBranchId?.branchId;
        setUsers(usersJson.filter(pu => pu.branchId === branchId));
        if(create) {
          reset({
            ...getValues(),
            keyOfficers: [{}]
          }, {
            errors: true, // errors will not be reset 
            dirtyFields: true, // dirtyFields will not be reset
            isDirty: true, // dirty will not be reset
          })
        }
      }, [append, getValues, reset, watchBranchId])
```

I wondering if there is a better to use useEffect, than what i have done

```
    import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
    import { useFormContext, Controller, useFieldArray, useWatch } from "react-hook-form";
    import {
      Form,
      Row,
      Col,
      Card,
      Button
    } from 'react-bootstrap';
    import moment from 'moment';
    import Select from "../../Shared/Select";
    import Datepicker from "../../Shared/Datepicker";
    import KeyOfficer from "../../Tooltips/KeyOfficer";
    import "../../Shared/style.css";
    import {Panel} from 'primereact/panel';
    
    // Data from JSON file
    import usersJson from '../../Dummy/ic4pro_users.json';
    import designatesJson from '../../Dummy/ic4pro_designates.json';
    import gradeJson from '../../Dummy/ic4pro_grades.json';
    
    const years = new Array(25 + 1).fill().map((e,i) => {
      return {label: i, value: i}
    });
    
    const months = new Array(10 + 1).fill().map((e,i) => {
      return {label: i, value: i}
    });
    
    const StepTwo = () => {
      const { register, errors, control, getValues, reset, selectedData, mode, setValue } = useFormContext();
    
      const { fields, append, remove } = useFieldArray({
        control,
        name: "keyOfficers"
      });
    
      const [ users, setUsers ] = useState([...usersJson])
    
      
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if(mode === 'create') append();
      }, [append])
    
      useEffect(() => {
        if(selectedData && (mode !== 'create' || mode === null)) {
          reset({
            ...getValues(),
            keyOfficers: selectedData.keyofficers.map(sd => ({
              staffName: users.find(uj => uj.userid === sd.staffName),
              datejoin: moment(sd.datejoin, 'YYYYMMDD').toDate(),
              jobStayYear: years.find(y => y.value === parseInt(sd.jobStayYear)),
              jobStayMonth: months.find(m => m.value === parseInt(sd.jobStayMonth))
            }))
          })
        }
        else {
          reset({
            keyOfficers: []
          })
        }
      }, [selectedData])
    
      const watchKeyOfficers = useWatch({ name: 'keyOfficers' });
    
      // Disable selected option on next select
      useEffect(() => {
        if(watchKeyOfficers) {
          setUsers(prevUsers => {
            const newWatchKeyOfficers = watchKeyOfficers.map(ko => ko.staffName?.userid);
            const newUsers = prevUsers?.map(u => ({ ...u, isDisabled: newWatchKeyOfficers.includes(u.userid) }))
            return newUsers;
          })
        }
      }, [watchKeyOfficers])
    
      const watchBranchId = useWatch({ name: 'branchId' });
      
      
    
    
      useEffect(() => {
        const branchId = watchBranchId?.branchId;
        setUsers(usersJson.filter(pu => pu.branchId === branchId));
        if(create) {
          reset({
            ...getValues(),
            keyOfficers: [{}]
          }, {
            errors: true, // errors will not be reset 
            dirtyFields: true, // dirtyFields will not be reset
            isDirty: true, // dirty will not be reset
          })
        }
      }, [append, getValues, reset, watchBranchId])
    
      const getDesignate = useCallback((designate) => {
        const designateFind = designatesJson.find(de => de.designate_id === designate)
        return designateFind?.designate_name;
      }, []);
    
      const getGrade = useCallback((gradelevel) => {
        const gradeFind = gradeJson.find(gr => gr.gradeID === gradelevel)
        return gradeFind?.gradeType;
      }, []);
    
      const header1 = (
        <>
        <div >  
          <div>Key Officer <KeyOfficer/></div>
        </div>
      </>
      )
    
      return (
        <Fragment>
          <Panel header={header1} className="p-col-12 mb-3">
                    
                    <Form.Group as={Row} >
                    <Form.Label column sm={3} style={{paddingLeft:"2rem"}}>
                      Staff Name
                    </Form.Label>
                    
                   
                    <Form.Label column sm={2}>
                      Grade Level
                    </Form.Label>
                    
                    
                    <Form.Label column sm={1}>
                      Function
                    </Form.Label>
                    
                    
                    <Form.Label column sm={2} className="text-center">
                      Length Of Stay
                    </Form.Label>
                    
                    <Form.Label column xs={2} >
                      Job Stay Year
                    </Form.Label>
                    
                    <Form.Label column sm={2}  >
                      Job Month
                    </Form.Label>
                    </Form.Group>
                    
                    
              {fields.map((item, index) => (
                <>
                <Row key={item.id}>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} sm="3" controlId={`keyOfficers[${index}].staffName`}>
                    
                    <Controller
                      // id="keyofficer"
                      name={`keyOfficers[${index}].staffName`}
                      as={Select}
                      options={users}
                      // hideSelectedOptions={false}
                      control={control}
                      getOptionValue={option => option.userid}
                      getOptionLabel={option => `${option.title}. ${option.firstName} ${option.lastName}`}
                      rules={{ required: 'Staff Name is required!' }}
                      isInvalid={errors.keyOfficers?.[index]?.staffName}
                      disabled={mode === 'view' || mode === 'delete'}
                      defaultValue={item.staffName || ""}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId={`keyOfficers[${index}].gradeLevel`}>
                    
                    <Form.Control 
                    id="gradelevel"
                    name={`keyOfficers[${index}].gradeLevel`} 
                    ref={register} 
                    style ={{height:'1.8rem', marginTop:0, marginBottom:0}} 
                    readOnly 
                    defaultValue={getGrade(watchKeyOfficers?.[index]?.staffName?.gradelevel)}/>
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId={`keyOfficers[${index}].designate`}>
                    
                    <Form.Control
                      name={`keyOfficers[${index}].designate`}
                      ref={register}
                      style ={{height:'1.8rem', marginTop:0, marginBottom:0}} 
                      readOnly
                      defaultValue={getDesignate(watchKeyOfficers?.[index]?.staffName?.designate)}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId={`keyOfficers[${index}].datejoin`}>
                    
                    <Controller
                      control={control}
                      name={`keyOfficers[${index}].datejoin`}
                      rules={{ required: 'Length of Stay is required!' }}
                      defaultValue={item.datejoin || ""}
                      render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
                        <Fragment >
                          <Datepicker
                            onChange={onChange}
                            onBlur={onBlur}
                            selected={value}
                            isInvalid={errors.keyOfficers?.[index]?.datejoin}
                            className="form-control is-invalid"
                            placeholderText="Length of Stay..."
                            disabled={mode === 'view' || mode === 'delete'}
                          />
                        </Fragment>
                      )}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId={`keyOfficers[${index}].jobStayYear`}>
                    
                    <Controller
                      name={`keyOfficers[${index}].jobStayYear`}
                      as={Select}
                      options={years}
                      control={control}
                      rules={{ required: 'Job Stay Year is required!' }}
                      isInvalid={errors.keyOfficers?.[index]?.jobStayYear}
                      disabled={mode === 'view' || mode === 'delete'}
                      defaultValue={item.jobStayYear || ""}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                  <Form.Group as={Col} controlId={`keyOfficers[${index}].jobStayMonth`}>
                    
                    <Controller
                      name={`keyOfficers[${index}].jobStayMonth`}
                      as={Select}
                      options={months}
                      control={control}
                      rules={{ required: 'Job Stay Month is required!' }}
                      isInvalid={errors.keyOfficers?.[index]?.jobStayMonth}
                      disabled={mode === 'view' || mode === 'delete'}
                      defaultValue={item.jobStayMonth || ""}
                    />
                  </Form.Group>
                  {(mode === 'create' || mode === 'edit') && (
                    <Form.Group as={Col} style={{marginTop:0, maxHeight:'1.8rem'}} controlId={`keyOfficers[${index}].delete`}
                      className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center" xs="auto"
                    >
                      <Button variant="danger" style={{marginTop:0, maxHeight:'1.8rem'}} size="sm" onClick={() => remove(index)}>Delete</Button>
                    </Form.Group>
                  )}
                </Row>
                
                </>
              ))}
              {(mode === 'create' || mode === 'edit') && (
              <Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" size="sm" style={{maxWidth:'7rem', maxHeight:'1.8rem'}} type="button" onClick={append}>Add Staff</Button>
              </Form.Group>
              )}
            </Panel>
        </Fragment>
      )
    }
    
    function compare(prevProps, nextProps) {
      return JSON.stringify(prevProps) === JSON.stringify(nextProps)
    }
    
    export default React.memo(StepTwo, compare);
```

Comment: This will be updated whenever `append` also receives an update, as it has a `useEffect` has a dependency. The question is, do you want `useEffect` to always be called when `append` is updated?

Comment: please create a smaller reproduction of your issue, it's hard to tell by looking at the component you sumbit.
for better understanding of `useEffect` your best learning resource is 
https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

Answer (score 1):

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(mode === 'create') append();
  }, [append]) //// Only re-run the effect if append changes
```

append() is executing in the effect, so each time the effect is called, it executes append(), which calls the effect again, which executes append() ... infinitely.

[From reactjs documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)